# How run logic after NavigationMixin.Navigate completes

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate, promises

This code works great.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__objectPage',
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName: this.selectedObject,
                    actionName: 'new',
                },
                state: {
                    useRecordTypeCheck: 1,
                    defaultFieldValues: defaultValues,
                    navigationLocation: navLocation,
                } 
            })
```

but, I would like to run logic after the completion of the record creation....something like this -

```
       this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__objectPage',
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName: this.selectedObject,
                    actionName: 'new',
                },
                state: {
                    useRecordTypeCheck: 1,
                    defaultFieldValues: defaultValues,
                    navigationLocation: navLocation,
                } 
            }).then(result => {
                //REFRESH THE PAGE HERE
            })
            .catch(error => {
                //MAYBE CATCH SOMETHING HERE
            });
```

But, I guess a Promise is not returned. I am getting the following error -

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this[navigation.NavigationMixin.Navigate](...) is undefined
```

How do I run some logic after the creation of the record using the LWC NavigationMixin.Navigate functionality?